# How to provide input in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've downloaded this Sudoku solver from net.

I'm trying to run the program in Eclipse. But I'm not sure how to provide input.

As I'm new to Java and Eclipse, I'm not sure how to do this.

Help please.

Here is the code:

```
public class Sudoku {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Load the matrix
    int[][] matrix = parseProblem(args);

    writeMatrix(matrix);

    //Find a solution
    if (solve(0, 0, matrix))
        writeMatrix(matrix);
    else
        System.out.println("NONE");
}

static boolean solve(int i, int j, int[][] cells) {

    if (i == 9) {
        i = 0;
        if (++j == 9) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (cells[i][j] != 0) {
        return solve(i + 1, j, cells);
    }

    for (int val = 1; val <= 9; ++val) {
        if (legal(i, j, val, cells)) {
            cells[i][j] = val;
            if (solve(i + 1, j, cells)) { 
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    //Reset
    cells[i][j] = 0;

    return false;
}

static boolean legal(int i, int j, int val, int[][] cells) {

    //Row
    for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) {
        if (val == cells[k][j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Column
    for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) {
        if (val == cells[i][k]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int boxRowOffset = (i / 3) * 3;
    int boxColOffset = (j / 3) * 3;

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
            if (val == cells[boxRowOffset + k][boxColOffset + m]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

static int[][] parseProblem(String[] args) {

    int[][] problem = new int[9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            problem[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(args[i].substring(j, j+1));
        }
    }

    return problem;
}

static void writeMatrix(int[][] solution) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {

        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(" -----------------------");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {

            if (j % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            }

            System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0 ? " " : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));

            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    System.out.println(" -----------------------");
}
}
```

Comment: When you run a program in Eclipse, you give input with the built in console

Comment: Original Source: http://www.colloquial.com/games/sudoku/java_sudoku.html

Comment: .. which also contains the expected format of the program arguments (at the very bottom).

Answer (score 3):

In your `parseProblem()` method, you are trying to read from command line arguments.

To provide command line arguments do the following steps:

Right click on the class. Select **Run As -> Run Configurations...**

Double click on **Java Application** on the left side panel.

Go to **(x)= Arguments** tab on the right side panel.

Under **Program Arguments** field, provide your input for the program.

In your case, input argument should be something similar to:

```
030400000
870306001
004980000
906034000
005000300
000750204
000043700
500608032
000002080
```

As per the code you downloaded, **"0"** represents blank value.

Answer (score 1):

This program is based on args[] that are given when you run the program so if you want it to run, you need to go to your cmd, go to the map your class is in and type this:

example: java Sudoku 091254876985235646586546545645646545645432435435484843521231564545648545643213541564654545313213541354384584514231354854668543215153144544384384354542135453454354451351351315584648648468 (you have to give 81 arguments because your sudoku contains 9*9 digits)